# Upload folder using filepond

Tags: upload, directory, filepond

I am trying add a functionality of uploading a folder using filepond but there is no such documentation for such,so how to upload a folder using filepond?

Comment: You can drop a folder, but it will upload the individual files. I'm not sure if the web offers a method to upload folders.

Comment: if a folder contains another folder then ,it fails to upload file inside the subdirectory and the GitHub page of filepond does have a closed issue of folder upload (https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/27) this implies that  the functionality is available, but I am unable to find any documentation regarding such.

Comment: FYI, drag/dropping a folder seems to work in Chrome but not Firefox.